# Can XpsDocuments be serialized to XML for storage in a database?

Tags: sql-server, xpsdocument

And, if not, is the only other alternative a blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPS documents are zip files that contain XML. You could extract the contents of the zip file and store that in the database, but then you would need to unzip and re-zip every time data came in or out of the database.

**Edit**:  In other words, not in any practical manner.